# How to operate bitwise? (Operator & cannot be applied to Integer or int)

Tags: java, android, bitwise-operators

I want to check some permissions on an android app, I got these permissions from an API I use for different devices and coding languages, but this is my first attempt on JAVA (Android), and seems it is different.

In my App these permissions are in a class which returns them as an `Integer`, so if I want to check if the user can delete (decimal 4) I want to do something like this:

```
if(MyClass.getBit()&4){ // Is bit 2 on?
    // Yes, is on
}
```

I got the following error:

> Required Boolean, Found Int.

That's ok, I can made it boolean:

```
if(MyClass.getBit()&4 != 0){ // Is bit&4 not 0?
    // Yes, it is different
}
```

I get a new error:

> Operator '&' cannot be applied to 'java.lang.Integer', 'boolean'

So I changed the returned value to `int`, I got the same:

> Operator '&' cannot be applied to 'int', 'boolean'

Seems like I am not going on the correct way...

**How to operate bitwises on Android?**

Comment: *FYI:* The literal `4` is the binary number `100`, and bits are numbered from the right, starting at 0, so that would be a test of bit **2**, not bit 4.

Comment: I am using bit 2 (binary`10`) for a different permission (read perm)

Comment: Binary `10` (decimal `2`) is a mask for testing bit **1**, because, as I already told you, bits are numbered from the right, starting at 0. Please use the correct terminology. Binary `1` (decimal `1`) tests bit **0**. Binary `10` (decimal `2`) tests bit **1**. Binary `100` (decimal `4`) tests bit **2**. Binary `1000` (decimal `8`) tests bit **3**. Binary `10000` (decimal `16`) tests bit **4**. And so on ...

Comment: I see what you mean, I edited my question to avoid using "bit" word and changed `bit 4` for `bit 2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a precedence issue, you have to add parentheses,

```
if ((MyClass.getBit()&4) != 0){ // Is bit&4 not 0?
    // Yes, it is different
}
```

Without parentheses, it would perform the  (4 != 0) part first, which returns a boolean, then do the AND operator on that boolean and the integer on the left.

Comment: And that solved the issue, was nothing to do with the operator or the value type, thank you!